# Python-Sql connection. Entries made in python terminal are not committing to the MySql server. Producing null table despite showing no error

Tags: python, mysql, api, backend

I am working on a small project which pertains the connectivity of python with MySql. What I have envisioned is that I will use Python to store the credentials like username and password to the database named `PENGUINX` I connected with MySql server. So far , my code looks clean and shows no error upon execution but when I go back to MySql workbench and attempt to display the logs Python has entered into the `Credents` table by runnning the command  `select * from credents;` , it gives me a null table, which apparently indicates that my entries are not committing to the server database.. The python-sql connectivity shows no defect when I try to create a table or a new database with python.

```
import random
import mysql.connector as boss
connection = boss.connect(host = 'localhost ', username = 'root', password = '********', database = 'penguinx')
control = connection.cursor()
control.execute('use penguinx ;')


print('---------DATABASE OF PENGUIN-X USERS CREDENTIALS---------')

def login_credentials():
    __ask_number_of_datachunks__ = int(input('How many credentials to be entered ? : '))
    for i in range(__ask_number_of_datachunks__) :
        ask_email = input('Enter Your Username : ')
        ask_pass = input('Enter Your password : ')
        assign_id = random.randint(1,100)
        control.execute('insert into credents values({},"{}","{}");'.format(assign_id,ask_email,ask_pass))
        control.commit()


login_credentials()
```

bear in mind that commit() in contron.commit() is not being considered as a function (not blending with the color of function code)

Comment: You have to commit your changes. Your data was only added to the db session but not committed

Comment: control.commit()

Comment: i ineveitibly did that , but the function doesnt work.. neither does it change the color of the code of the .commit() function

Comment: AttributeError: 'CMySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'commit' 

gives me this error when i run the code.

Comment: Does the table exist?

Comment: yes , the table exist with columns as userid , username , password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253180/discussion-between-lunaticxxd10-and-maxwell-d-dorliea).

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved using `connection.commit()`. Dont't confuse yourself with using the cursor variable to commit changes. (ie.. `control.commit()` in this case is gonna worsen the problem).